# SQLite3 selecting entries inserted within last 24 hours in Flask

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, flask

I am new to flask and SQLite3. I want to select the entries inserted into the table from the past 24 hours.

the entries are inserted as follows:

```
    now=datetime.now()
    formatted_date=now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    ip=request.remote_addr
    txt=request.form['txt']
    with sql.connect("static/database.db") as con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('INSERT into messagetable (txt,dateandtime,ip) values (?,?,?)',(txt,formatted_date,ip))
    con.commit()
```

and the selection is done by:

```
   con = sql.connect("static/database.db")
   con.row_factory = sql.Row

   cur = con.cursor()
   cur.execute('SELECT * FROM messagetable WHERE (current_date-dateandtime<1)')
   rows = cur.fetchall();
```

But the final result shows all the entries in the table, and not exclusively the ones posted within the last 24 hours. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM messagetable WHERE dateandtime >= date('now', '-1 days') AND dateandtime < date('now')")
```